# How to prove that the size of the set that is a collection of all finite unions of $n$ disjoint sets is $2^n-1$?

Tags: combinatorics

I came across the following example.

Let $X = [0, 1]$, and let $B_1,\dots, B_8$  be subsets of X
which are pairwise disjoint and whose union is all of X. Let A be
the collection of all finite unions of the $B_i$'s as well as the empty
set. (Thus A consists of $2^8$ elements.)

How do we prove that such a set has $2^8$ elements? I tried to start with 2 such sets and building up to larger sets but I do not see the pattern.

Comment: Consider the power set.

Comment: For each of the $B_i$, you have $2$ choices: include it or don't.  That gives $2^8$ possibilities, by the multiplicative principle.

Comment: @saulspatz Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: Sorry for my quirky question... What is $X$? An interval? The set with the two elements $0,1$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, X is the closed interval from 0 to 1. If it were a set, I would have used curly brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy combinatoric way is to consider the process of creating an element of $A$. Each element of $A$ can be uniquely created by a unique choice of some (or none) of $B_i$. This is essentially a bijection.

Hence, in the process of creating an element of $A$, each $B_i$ has $2$ choices: either to form part of the union that is the element of $A$, or to not be part of it. Hence, there are a total of $2^8$ ways to create elements of $A$. This argument is easily generalized.

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways of taking finite unions is exactly the number of ways of choosing a finite number of $B_i$'s. This is because you can just choose a finite number of $B_i$'s and put unions in between.

But, that's same as creating the power set of $A=\{B_i:i\in\{1,2,\dots 8\}\}$.

So, the number of ways in which it can be done is $2^8$.